# How to disable div blocks having a certain id pattern?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, userscripts

I would like to write a greasemonkey script to disable a div on a certain page.
On any given load of the page I don't know where in the DOM the div will be but I know it's always called `<div id = "alertPanel"> ....</div>`

How would I go about disabling this div?

My intial thoughts were something along the lines of:

```
var myDivs= document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (i=0; i<myDivs.length; i++)
{

  if (myDivs[i].<get id property somehow> = "alertPanel")
     myDivs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
 }
```

but as you can tell I'm stuck at accessing the id property for an equality check.

Incidently, I'm using a text editor to write this - I guessing that a standard javascript editor would give an autocompletion list after typing in `myDivs[i].`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it has an `id`, you can use [`document.getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId):

```
var div = document.getElementById("alertPanel");
```

Then if it exists, you can either remove it (probably a bad idea) or hide it:

```
if (div) {
    div.style.display = "none"; // Hides it
    // Or
    // div.parentNode.removeChild(div); // Removes it entirely
}
```

**Update**: Re your comment on another answer:

> thanks for your answer. Does your statemt apply to a page with iframes too. The div in question is in an iframe. I've tried ypur solution and it didn't work unfortunately. maybe a link to the page will help: tennis.betfair.com the div i want to disable is the one with id: minigamesContainer

If the element is in an `iframe`, then you have to call `getElementById` on the document that's in the `iframe`, since `iframe`s are separate windows and have separate documents. If you know the `id` of the `iframe`, you can use `document.getElementById` to get the `iframe` instance, and then use `contentDocument` to access its document, and then use `getElementById` on *that* to get the "minigamesContainer" element:

```
var iframe, div;
iframe = document.getElementById("the_iframe_id");
if (iframe) {
    try {
        div = iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("minigamesContainer");
        if (div) {
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
}
```

(The `try/catch` is there because of a potential security error accessing the content of the iframe; I don't know Greasemonkey well enough to know whether the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) applies to it. I tend to assume it doesn't, but better safe...)

If you don't know the `id` of the `iframe` or if it doesn't have one, you can just loop through all of them by getting them with [`document.getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094) and then looping:

```
var iframes, index, iframe, div;
iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for (index = 0; index < iframes.length; ++index) {
    iframe = iframes[index];
    try {
        div = iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("minigamesContainer");
        if (div) {
            div.style.display = "none";
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
}
```

References:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [HTML5 Web Applications APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis)

Comment: This works great - thank you - but what if, instead of looking for just `alertPanel`, I **also** wanted to hide an `alertPanel2` or `alertPanel3`? (I’m trying to learn the basics of javascript - I’m a little nervous about experimenting.)

Answer (score 1):

In valid HTML you can have only element with certain ID. So:

```
document.getElementById('alertPanel').style.visiblity = 'hidden';
```

But if you still need to iterate all div's and check their ID's, then this should work:

```
if (myDivs[i].id == "alertPanel") myDivs[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Comment: Note that an element with `visibility:hidden` takes up space on the screen even when not shown whereas an element with `display:none` does not.